# One to Many join in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have tow tables, one collar table with drillhole unique numbers with  their x,y,z values and second table with drillhole numbers with geology information and one drillhole can have many geology information based on drillhole depth. I want to join two table. Would you please how can I join these two table in ms access. I want all the data from drillhole collar table and only matching data from geology table. I am trying but could not succeed. Please advise.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQAYD.png)

[Two Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX17p.png)

Comment: You provide geology table structure but not the collar table. What are the x,y,z values - Lat, Long, Elev? If both tables have HoleID then this appears to be a simple JOIN query. What does 'not succeed' mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Post attempted query SQL statement. Post sample of collar table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data from a master table (drillhole collar table) plus matching data from a child table (geology table), this is achieved by using a `LEFT JOIN` query. Adapt this example by replacing the table and column names with ones that you need from your database:

```
SELECT d.*, g.*
FROM Drillhole d
LEFT JOIN Geology g ON d.Hole_ID = g.Hole_ID
```